# How can i implement menu view like whats app attach menu?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I need to implement a menu view like whats app attach menu. Does any third party framework available in the net please share

Comment: anyway (UIDesign/programatically)

Comment: you can implement as you wish

Answer (score 1):

You don not any third party library for that. It is iOS feature called `UIActionSheet`. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/) is a link from apple documentation. And [here](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/action-sheet-tutorial-ios8-swift) is a link how you can use `UIActionSheet` using Swift.